# Swift Regex for extracting words between parenthesis

Tags: regex, swift

Hello i wanna extract the text between ().

For example :

```
(some text) some other text -> some text
(some) some other text      -> some
(12345)  some other text    -> 12345
```

the maximum length of the string between parenthesis should be 10 characters.

```
(TooLongStri) -> nothing matched because 11 characters
```

what i have currently is :

```
let regex   = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\(\\w+\\)", options: [])

regex.enumerateMatchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (text as NSString).length))
{
    (result, _, _) in
        let match = (text as NSString).substringWithRange(result!.range)

        if (match.characters.count <= 10)
        {
            print(match)
        }
}
```

which works nicely but the matches are :

```
(some text) some other text -> (some text)
(some) some other text      -> (some)
(12345)  some other text    -> (12345)
```

and doesn't match <=10 because () are counted also.

How can i change the code above to solve that? I would like also to remove the `if (match.characters.count <= 10)`by extending the regex to hold the length info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
"(?<=\\()[^()]{1,10}(?=\\))"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO6eB7/1)

The pattern:

- `(?<=\\()` - asserts the presence of a `(` before the current position and fails the match if there is none
- `[^()]{1,10}` - matches 1 to 10 characters other than `(` and `)` (replace `[^()]` with `\w` if you need to only match alphanumeric / underscore characters)
- `(?=\\))` - checks if there is a literal `)` after the current position, and fail the match if there is none.

If you can adjust your code to get the value at Range 1 (capture group) you can use a simpler regex:

```
"\\(([^()]{1,10})\\)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO6eB7/2). The value you need is inside Capture group 1.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
\((?=.{0,10}\)).+?\)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW3qI7/2)**

This will also work

```
\((?=.{0,10}\))([^)]+)\)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW3qI7/4)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\( #Match the bracket literally
(?=.{0,10}\)) #Lookahead to check there are between 0 to 10 characters till we encounter another )
([^)]+) #Match anything except )
\) #Match ) literally
```